# Call a function from outside a class - Python

Tags: python, function

Having some trouble calling `stream_to_stop()` from within `StreamingForexPrices`..  The following code gives this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method stream_to_stop() must be called with StreamingForexPrices instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

Can someone please help me understand?  Thanks

```
class StreamingForexPrices(object):
    def __init__(
        self, domain, access_token,
        account_id, instruments, events_queue
    ):
        self.domain = domain
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.account_id = account_id
        self.instruments = instruments
        self.events_queue = events_queue

    def stream_to_stop(self):
        response = self.connect_to_stream()
        if response.status_code != 200:
            return
        for line in response.iter_lines(1):
            if line:
                try:
                    msg = json.loads(line)
                except Exception as e:
                    print "Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e)
                    return
                if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                    print msg["tick"]["ask"] - .001
                    instrument = msg["tick"]["instrument"]
                    time = msg["tick"]["time"]
                    bid = msg["tick"]["bid"]
                    ask = msg["tick"]["ask"]
                    stopLoss = msg["tick"]["ask"] - .001
                    tev = StopEvent(stopLoss)
                    self.events_queue.put(tev)

stop = StreamingForexPrices.stream_to_stop()
print stop
```

My goal is to print the output of stream_to_stop..  Thanks again!

Edited indentation..

Comment: Not super familiar with python, but I think you're calling a class method without creating the object. try creating a ````StreamingForexPrices```` object and then calling the function?

Comment: You aren't actually creating an **instance** of `StreamingForexPrices`. Should `stream_to_stop` be a `@classmethod`? Given that you have two methods, one of which is `__init__`, you might find this useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0

Comment: `stream_to_stop` is not a method of `StreamingForexPrices`. Is the indentation right? And if it's a method of `StreamingForexPrices` then you should call it on an instance of `StreamingForexPrices`, not on the class itself.

Comment: No the indentation is not correct, I took a bunch of stuff out that wasn't needed for the question..  And that would make a lot more sense as far as not creating an instance

Comment: @jonrsharpe - great link!  Just watched the first few minutes and I definitely have my work cut out for me..  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
domain = "www.example.com"
access_token = "ldkjflekfjelkxlk"
account_id = "account"
instruments = ["some instrument I don't how to play"]
events_queue = xxx # It sounds like an object created to handle queue
stop = StreamingForexPrices(domain, access_token, account_id, instruments, events_queue).stream_to_stop()
```

[How to use python class](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner's_Python_Tutorial/Classes)

Comment: Thanks @Shuo..  This gives me the error 'NameError: name 'domain' is not defined'

Comment: @user2883183 well obviously you'll need to define the parameters you pass to `__init__` - where were you expecting them to come from?

Comment: Got it..  I had taken out the parameters when writing the question here.  Thanks a lot guys!